# gVimDiff in Nemo context menu

Tags: linux-ubuntu

On Windows I'm used to have the gVimDiff context menu when two or more files are selected in Windows Explorer.

Is there something similar for Nemo on Ubuntu? I searched for the string in the title and nothing relevant seemed to have been returned.